# Jquery reverse function on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to reverse a click function when the browser is resized? As of now my menu toggle is working as expected. The problem is when the browser resizes the menu is staying open and the overlay is still active.

I attempted to call functions on a window resize event but had no luck. I would like the functions reversed at 768px

```
$nav_list.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toleft');
  $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
  $('.menu-open-overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: You just need to hook to the `resize` event of the `window` and add/remove the relevant classes to whatever state gets rid of the menu.

Comment: Or just use media queries?

Comment: my advice is to never 'toggle'  classes, check their presence and set them to what is needed. Then you can easily include cases for screen sizes.